# JQuery animation works incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 forms, 2 of them hidden. I press link to change one visible form to other. So I need to make an animation of extension or constriction when I change active form. Now I have this, but it is not working correctly:

```
$('.message a').click(function(){
       $('.form form').addClass('hidden');
       var form = $(this).attr('for');
       $('.' + form + '').animate({ height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow").removeClass('hidden');
   });
```

If i use:

```
$('.message a').click(function(){
       $('.form form').addClass('hidden');
       var form = $(this).attr('for');
       $('.' + form + '').removeClass('hidden');
   });
```

It works correctly, but dont make animation.
How can I fix it? Thanks and have a Happy New Year!

```js
$('.message a').click(function(){
       $('.form form').addClass('hidden');
       var form = $(this).attr('for');
       $('.' + form + '').removeClass('hidden');
   });
```

```css
body {
 font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative; top: 25px; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 25px;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;

}

.form button {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #5d98cc;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
  background: #397eba;
}
.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
  color: #5d98cc;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.container .info {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .info h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}
.container .info span {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.container .info span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container .info span .fa {
  color: #EF3B3A;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.error-message {
  color: #dc2d2d;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.input-error {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-image:url(http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/icons/cancel.svg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  background-position: 95% 50%;
}
.input-correct {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-image:url(http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/icons/checked.svg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  background-position: 95% 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="login-page">
    <div class="form">

      <form class="register-form hidden" method="POST" action="{% url 'signup' %}" id = "formregister">

          <input class="input" type="text"
                 name="username" placeholder="имя пользователя" maxlength="150"/>

          <input  class="input"  type="text"
                 name="email" placeholder="email"/>

          <input class="input" type="password" id="password1"
                  name="password1" placeholder="пароль"/>

          <input class="input" type="password" id="password2"
                 name="password2" placeholder="повторите пароль"/>

          <div class="errorTxtReg error-message">
                    


          </div>

          <button type="submit">создать</button>


          <p class="message">Уже зарегистрированны? <a href="#" id ="alogin-reg" for="login-form">Войти.</a></p>
          <p class="message">Забыли пароль? <a href="#" id ="arestore-reg" for="reset-form">Восстановить.</a></p>
      </form>


      <form class="login-form" method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}" id = "formlogin">
   

          <input class="input" type="text" name="username"
          placeholder="имя пользователя" maxlength="254"/>

          <input class="input" type="password" name="password"
          placeholder="пароль" maxlength="254"/>

          <div class="errorTxtLog error-message"></div>

           <button type="submit">войти</button>

           <p class="message">Не зарегистрированны? <a href="#" id ="aregister-log" for="register-form">Создать аккаунт.</a></p>
           <p class="message">Забыли пароль? <a href="#" id ="arestore-log" for="reset-form">Востановить.</a></p>
      </form>



      <form class="reset-form hidden" method="POST" action="{% url 'reset'%}" id = "formreset">
 

          <input class="input" type="text" name="email"
                 placeholder="email" maxlength="200" />

          <div class="errorTxtRes error-message"></div>

          <button type="submit">Восстановить</button>

          <p class="message">Не зарегистрированны? <a href="#" id ="aregister-res" for="register-form">Создать аккаунт.</a></p>
          <p class="message">Уже зарегистрированны? <a href="#" id ="alogin-res" for="login-form">Войти.</a></p>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Added:

```
 $('.message a').click(function(){
       $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
    });
```

Comment: post html and relevant css for it

Comment: what you expect from `height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"` to do??

Comment: edited and added HTML and CSS

Comment: Add a minimal and working code snippet

Comment: the code snippet does nothing like described in the problem.

Comment: well you would have to clean it up to make a working example.

Comment: Made it. Didnt clean some extra 'if' from backend, the question is all about that animation:).

Comment: How are we gone make a working example trying to make this html/css/js to work with all that extra markup? I'm suppose to clean it for you? Read the rules on posting questions

Comment: Made it guys. Check. Used working js with no animation.

Answer (score 1):

Your js is not correct. "Toggle" is not a valid value for height and opacity. There is also the issue with not being able to animate `height` with `auto`. A question, why do you set `.hidden` on the forms? Looking into your html I can see it contains not valid html, like `<a>` does not have `for` that is `<label>`.

In your case you can go with two routes.

1. you use `slideToggle();` in jQuery
2. you animate the max-height and set it to a approximate value

In the example I used #2 (to follow your example)

Also for this you need to add `overflow: hidden;` on the form (I made that in the css). Also You can change the jquery from `.click()` to `.on('click')`, that would be a recommendation to get into.

I find it more clear to play around in jsfiddle, [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hs9pnrts/)

```js
$('.message a').on('click', function() {
  $('.form form').addClass('hidden');
  var form = $(this).attr('for');

  $('.' + form).animate({
"maxHeight": 400,
'opacity': 1
  }, "slow").removeClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
body {
 font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative; top: 25px; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 25px;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
overflow: hidden;
}
.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;

}

.form button {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #5d98cc;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
  background: #397eba;
}
.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
  color: #5d98cc;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.container .info {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .info h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}
.container .info span {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.container .info span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container .info span .fa {
  color: #EF3B3A;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.error-message {
  color: #dc2d2d;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.input-error {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-image:url(http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/icons/cancel.svg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  background-position: 95% 50%;
}
.input-correct {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-image:url(http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/icons/checked.svg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  background-position: 95% 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="login-page">
    <div class="form">

      <form class="register-form hidden" method="POST" action="{% url 'signup' %}" id = "formregister">

          <input class="input" type="text"
                 name="username" placeholder="имя пользователя" maxlength="150"/>

          <input  class="input"  type="text"
                 name="email" placeholder="email"/>

          <input class="input" type="password" id="password1"
                  name="password1" placeholder="пароль"/>

          <input class="input" type="password" id="password2"
                 name="password2" placeholder="повторите пароль"/>

          <div class="errorTxtReg error-message">
                    


          </div>

          <button type="submit">создать</button>


          <p class="message">Уже зарегистрированны? <a href="#" id ="alogin-reg" for="login-form">Войти.</a></p>
          <p class="message">Забыли пароль? <a href="#" id ="arestore-reg" for="reset-form">Восстановить.</a></p>
      </form>


      <form class="login-form" method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}" id = "formlogin">
   

          <input class="input" type="text" name="username"
          placeholder="имя пользователя" maxlength="254"/>

          <input class="input" type="password" name="password"
          placeholder="пароль" maxlength="254"/>

          <div class="errorTxtLog error-message"></div>

           <button type="submit">войти</button>

           <p class="message">Не зарегистрированны? <a href="#" id ="aregister-log" for="register-form">Создать аккаунт.</a></p>
           <p class="message">Забыли пароль? <a href="#" id ="arestore-log" for="reset-form">Востановить.</a></p>
      </form>



      <form class="reset-form hidden" method="POST" action="{% url 'reset'%}" id = "formreset">
 

          <input class="input" type="text" name="email"
                 placeholder="email" maxlength="200" />

          <div class="errorTxtRes error-message"></div>

          <button type="submit">Восстановить</button>

          <p class="message">Не зарегистрированны? <a href="#" id ="aregister-res" for="register-form">Создать аккаунт.</a></p>
          <p class="message">Уже зарегистрированны? <a href="#" id ="alogin-res" for="login-form">Войти.</a></p>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, but this is not the animation I expected:(. I added JS to main theme which shows the right animation, which I try to make.

Comment: @D.Make that js does not tell me anything as it's not valid. What is your expected animation? A height animation is gone slide, opacity in your case is gone do nothing as you don't have opacity set.

Comment: the script i expect is opening the form i need on click, using opacity for form content (for smooth content change) and sliding for form div (making higher if opening form becomes bigger and making smaller if opening form becomes smaller). Do I need to rewrite JS using slideToggle?

Comment: @D.Make `slideToggle()` is not using `opacity`, so you probably won't get that expected behaviour. Just so I got this clear, you want the form to expand first and then the content to fade in with opacity?

Comment: I want conent form expand (or get smaller if goal content smaller) and the same time formBefore disapears (using opacity) whithin 1-2 seconds, and formAfter becomes (also using opacity) within the same time.